# Cordova (4.0) camera plugin does not work

Tags: android, cordova, ant, cordova-plugins

i'm learning to use Cordova 4.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 then i just try to test the Cordova **camera plugin 0.3.6** creating a new application, ex:

```
cordova create camerApp com.cameratest.app camerApp
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

Once i have installed the camera plugin i run the next command to test if everything is going right

```
cordova build
```

or the another command:

```
cordova emulate andorid
```

but i got the next error from the CLI

```
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/xfry/coding/cordova/mycameraApp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/xfry/coding/cordova/mycameraApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/xfry/coding/cordova/mycameraApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

It is the right way to implement the camera plugin? or i should do more things to get running it?

what suppose to i can do to fix this error? Some of you had the same error?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below cordova plugin,
It works fine for me dont go for third party plugins.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make use of comments for informative or critique content once you earn enough reputations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @praba I continued having the same error usign this plugin :( i have reviewed the configuration of the file **platform/android/res/xml/config.xml** and i have the same coifiguration the link you shared, too i reviewed the file **platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml** and i have a good configuration as show the link you shared.

Comment: @xfry Can you share the configuration code/script here for better understanding and please share more information like, are you testing it in real device or emulator? whats the android version you are testing?

Comment: @Daenarys : Thanks for your greetings will do improve the usage of comments once i earn the enough reputations.

Comment: @AtanuCSE : Thanks for the mentions will update my answer with the required information.